# Recursive Regexp in nested group

Tags: regex

I have to parse some strings using regexps... But i came across these two:

> /: 13% used (1192/9919 MB) /var: 81% used (22881/29758 MB) /opt: 2% used (151/9919 MB) : (c,w) = (95,90)

and

> C: 65% used (37382/57105 MB) D: 11% used (6551/57205 MB) : (c,w) = (95,90)

they're the same, except for the number of occurrences. Is there any way I could parse that no matter how many times that group appears?

Comment: It would help folks if you showed what you needed to parse... so given these strings I would like my results to be ...

Comment: Also you will get more responses if you say... I tried this (show code) and it didn't work...

Comment: `^(.*?\))+$` can match both of your input. But i don't understand what you want to know.

Comment: I have a lot (hundreds) of strings just like those. but the part "/: 13% used (1192/9919 MB)" repeats itself a different number of times in each message.
I'd like to catch "1. C 2. 65 3. 37382 4. 57105 5. D 6. 11 7. 6551 8. 57205", using the second string as example
But the pattern is the same, is there anyway I can have it parse that pattern as many times as it appears in the message?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you might split the string into two halves each ( http://rubular.com/r/FB4WqFDSvJ ):

```
\s*((?:[^:]+: \d\d?% used \(\d+\/\d+ \w+\) )+?): (\(c,w\) = \(\d+,\d+\))\s*
```

Then, you might identify and remove one piece at a time in a loop ( http://rubular.com/r/IqEfL0NFxv ):

```
\s*([^:]+: \d\d?% used \(\d+\/\d+ \w+\))\s*
```